# robotframework if method returns true

Tags: robotframework

In my test I have a lot of conditional parts that are depended on the same function 'get max duration passed'
It is a python method that returns True or False
E.g.

```
  FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    9999999
    ${max_passed}  get max duration passed
    Exit For Loop If    ${max_passed}
```

I have a lot of places where I have e.g. 'run keyword if' where I first put the outcome of 'get max duration passed' inside a variable and than use the variable.

Is there a way to use the method directly?
like:

```
  FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    9999999
    Exit For Loop If    get max duration passed
```

*Using robotframework 3.1.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

Because "Exit For Loop If" requires a boolean condition which can be evaluated and not a keyword or a method which returns boolean in your case.